# Dynamic Programming help LISA- SPOJ

Tags: algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem - http://www.spoj.pl/problems/LISA/

I thought of Greedy initially, but realized later that it wouldn't work. 
It seems like a DP problem. 
 I'm not able to form the recurrence relation. 
I'm not able to form the recurrence relation. It's not just this problem, but I get stuck whenever I encounter a slightly difficult DP problem. I know this must be common and practice would help. But I am just moving from one problem to another without actually finding the solution.

Any advise would be great, on the above problem and in general, DP encounters.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that operations allowed are only `+` and `*` - binary operations that are strictly increasing in regard to both operands (they are positive).

Let `dp[l][r]` be the maximum outcome from substring [l,r]

Here are tips about this problem, which also apply to every dp.

1) What are base cases? (HINT: something very simple, that doesn't change its value with adding/removing brackets)

2) How do you move from bigger problem to smaller problem(s)? (HINT: you can try to find the place of last operation)

Comment: can't this be solved using stack? As we have only two operators we can assign lower priority for '+' in the first case and solve it. Later it can be assigned higher priority and solve it. It can be solved same as RPN(reverse polish notation).

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation of Matrix Chain Multiplication is just required to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little?

Answer (score 0):

1. there will be n/2+1 numbers

   2. n/2 sign
   3. allocate each sign with the number left to it.
   4. create a square matrix initialize diagonal with corresponding numbers, now i,j=max((i,k)(sign right of kth number)(k+1,j)) i<=k
   5. (0,m-1) will the answer
   6. Notice it directed flow toward (0,m-1) hence a DAG(Directed Acyclic Graph).
   7. **Thumb rule**: If any graphical representation of the problem can be optimised to DAG,it is solvable by DP

For solution refer:
https://shashankmishracoder.wordpress.com/2019/03/29/spoj-lisa-matrix-chain-multiplication-variation/